# Will numpy read the whole data every time it iterates?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a very large data file consists of N*100 real numbers, where N is very large. I want to read the data by columns. I can read it as whole then manipulate it column by column:

```
data=np.loadtxt(fname='data.txt')
for i in range(100):
    np.sum(data[:,i])
```

Or I can read it column by column and expecting this will save memory and be fast:

```
for i in range(100):
    col=np.loadtxt(fname='data.txt',usecols=(i,))
    np.sum(col)
```

However, the second approach seems not to be faster. **Is it because every time the code read the whole data and extract the desired the column?** So it is 100 times slower than the first one. **Is there any method to read one column after another but much faster?**

If I just want to get the 100 number at last row from the file, **reading the whole col and get the last elements is not wise choice, how to achieve this?**

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you want only the last row. This would read only the last row for `N` rows:

```
data = np.loadtxt(fname='data.txt', skiprows=N-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking two things: how to sum across all rows, and how to read the last row.

```
data=np.loadtxt(fname='data.txt')
for i in range(100):
    np.sum(data[:,i])
```

`data` is a `(N,100)` 2d array.  You don't need to iterate to sum along each column

```
np.sum(data, axis=0)
```

gives you a (100,) array, one sum per column.

```
for i in range(100):
    col=np.loadtxt(fname='data.txt',usecols=(i,))
    np.sum(col)  # just throwing this away??
```

With this you read the file 100 times. In each `loadtxt` call it has to read each line, select the `ith` string, interpret it, and collect it in `col`.  It might be faster, IF `data` was so large that the machine bogged down with memory swapping.  Other wise, array operations on `data` will be lot faster than file reads.

As the other answer shows `loadtxt` lets you specify a `skiprows` parameter.  It will still read all the lines (i.e. `f.readline()` calls), but it just doesn't process them and collect the values in a list.

Do some of your own time tests.

Comment: So obtain the last row, how can it be faster?

Comment: Faster than what?  I expect that skipping all but the last row will be faster than loading them all into an array, but I don't know by how much.  I'm not interesting in creating a large test file to find out.

Comment: If I understand you correctly. Reading the datafile as a whole is the minimum time method.

Comment: Faster than skiprows=N-1. I remembered in language c, you can shift the pointer to anywhere you like.

Comment: If you have already loaded the whole `data` array, then it is trivial to look at the last row.  Just as it is easy to look any one column.  But if all you want is the last row, then you can load just that with the `skiprows` parameter.  Do you want **both** the column sums and the last row, or **just** the last row?

Comment: just last row, so I think it would be unnecessary to load the whole data.